# Redirect my facebook app to the requested url after facebook authentication

Tags: php, python, html, facebook

I am developing an app for facebook. the problem is suppose a non authenticated user requests the following url in my domain : 
`http://example.com/name/3242`

I redirect it to facebook's oauth page to authenticate the user and authorize the app, after both, i want facebook to request the same above url in the canvas. Any Help? or am i missing something (the fb docs seem to unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Facebook docs here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

You need to spec the `redirect_uri` parameter when you send them to Facebook to authenticate. When they successfully authenticate, Facebook will send them back to this URL like so:

```
http://example.com/name/3242?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER
```

If it fails, they will be sent to your URL like this:

```
http://example.com/name/3242?error_reason=user_denied&
     error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
```